# How to display a circle avatar image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When using the folloing code I would expect a circle avatar image but getting an oval. I tried different parameters like width and height on the Container but that didn't help.

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.star_border, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            //height: 25.0,
            // width: 25.0,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mChgTiAe-N8ibcM3fB_qvGdl2vQ9jvjYv0iOOjB=s96-c'),
            )
            /*
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mChgTiAe-N8ibcM3fB_qvGdl2vQ9jvjYv0iOOjB=s96-c')),
            ),*/
          ),
        ],
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are receiving an oval shape because you are using the `CircleAvatar` widget in `Appbar` widget which has limited height.

Try adding a parameter `radius` inside `CircleAvatar` Widget 
it will return the circle shape you want for the image.

try changing radius size value, according to your need.

```
CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mChgTiAe-N8ibcM3fB_qvGdl2vQ9jvjYv0iOOjB=s96-c'),
         radius: 15.0
        )
```

Comment: Solved my problem, thank you. I still don't understand why the `height` value of the container is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue in the past and have found that wrapping the AvatarCircle in a container with 58 width fixes the Circle radius ratio issue, making it a proper circle shape. One pixel more or less may fit your liking. Give this a try:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: new Icon(Icons.star_border, color: Colors.black),
      onPressed: () => {},
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 58.0,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mChgTiAe-N8ibcM3fB_qvGdl2vQ9jvjYv0iOOjB=s96-c'),
        )
      ),
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this  code and  works  with every  image  size...

```
 CircleAvatar(
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Image.network(items.logo, fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 30,
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works for me other than wrapping `CircleAvatar` with `padding` of `8.0`.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: CircleAvatar(
    ...
  ),
)
```